# Fixing "Unfortunately, DMG has stopped working" on Lenovo tablets

Tags: tablet, system-error, lenovo

My Lenovo IdeaTab S6000H tablet running on Android 4.2.2 Jelly Bean had worked fine before yesterday when suddenly it turned off, and after a restart, it has shown this message periodically:

> Unfortunately, DMG has stopped working

I also did a factory reset, but after turning it on, the same error message has been showing again.

How to fix this error?

Comment: I think some data got corrupted, I'd suggest that you flash a stock firmware. Should fix it

Comment: If you mean factory reset, I already have done it, but the message appears again

Comment: No, I don't mean factory reset. Flashing a device is programming it meaning reinstalling all the system stuff like installing Windows on a computer for example. So as one of your device components doesn't work properly, you neer to reinstall it hence flashing.

Comment: OK, I am going to try it.
But how do I flash it?

Comment: You need flash files and a flasher. Which model is your Lenovo Tablet?

Comment: the problem has been about the broken charge socket.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the mounting state of sdcard, maybe it’s broken. Suggest to call the customer service phone for examining further.

Comment: it don't has any external sdcard

Answer (score -3):

Its an malware app. Go to settings >apps>all apps>DMG>force stop>disable or uninstall

Comment: Any backing for that this is a malware app?

Comment: there s no uninstall option, but the disable , and force stop options,  haven't solved the problem